# Name a Windows app that will open-up the internet connection of a remote Windows machine so that I can browse as the remote from my home office?

Tags: windows, networking, tunnel

I need the following set-up for some app testing.

I would like to use the connection of a remote Windows machine from home.

I've been looking for some kind of tunnelling app for Windows that would open up a connection I can access.

Unfortunately, VPNs on the remote/ work network are not an option.

Ideally, we're looking for a software GUI solution...

Answer (score 0):

What about Remote Desktop?
Should be the easiest to set up:

- Enable port forwarding on the work machine for rdp so you can access it from outside the work network
- RDP is encrypted by default, so this should be reasonably secure

Comment: Looking for an app to do the port forwarding part?